# Executing tests from prompt and eclipse has different results

Tags: java, unit-testing, test-environments

When I run:
mvn clean install in prompt, I'm receiving some broken tests' message.

Executing the "Run as jUnit tests" on eclipse, I've got no errors.

Do you know where can I find the differences between this two ways?

Comment: What are the differences? One possible place to look is the classpath. Maven maintains different classpaths for test and non-test while eclipse only has one classpath for a project (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224708).

Comment: I think, you also need to provide more details about error message. Are those not valid errors?

Comment: Also, does error happens at `mvn test` too? My suggestion is to consider `mvn` results as final ones and not to rely on `Eclipse` runs.

Comment: @SabirKhan I'm not sure if my prompt result is valid, due to when executing in other pc prompt, it works. Other things that I noted: - Running 'mvn test' break in both of them. - Running only the class (doesn't break in eclipse and prompt) - Running all tests in eclipse breaks it too